# How to fix a (possibly) corrupt flash drive?

Tags: fdisk, data-corruption

To preface, I'm relatively new with linux-based systems, so please try to keep things relatively simple.

Before experiencing any issues, I had an 8GB flash drive that was recognized by

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

as /dev/sdb. The issue happened when I tried to copy a file onto the drive using

```
sudo dd if=[File] of=/dev/null bs=512k
```

where [File] was a file in my working directory. I realized I had done something I didn't want to do and force closed the terminal before the task finished. When I reopened it and checked

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

again, it listed the drives and devices, but got stuck trying to find /dev/sdb. It simply doesn't show up and won't let me type into the terminal any further. I believe I may have corrupted the drive by mistake.

Is there any way to get the drive back or do I need to buy a new one?

---

EDIT:

I tried

```
gksu gparted
```

and it requires admin password. I thought I defined that when I put Ubuntu on the computer, but the password isn't working.

Comment: Unplug the drive and put it back in, then use `gksu gparted` to locate it and create a new partition table for `msdos`, after that create a new volume on it and you should get your drive back. but the data on it will be lost I assume.

Comment: I think you just need to format it. Needless to say, there is no need to buy a new one.

Comment: Use the password for your ordinary user (for gksu), the same password as you use to log in as your ordinary user.

Comment: If `gparted` does not solve the problem for you, try `mkusb` and analyze the problem according to the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035